# Excel filter vanishes after change in sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a excel-file with multiple sheets.
Sheet1 (Lagerliste) holds a bunch of logistics-data. Mainly: WHAT is WHERE

In a seperate sheet I want to filter all lines containing a certain value (Selfservice) in a row (B). 
I accomplish this with a VBA-macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Filters LagerlisteHW Row B for the word "Selfservice" and copys the corresponding lines
    ' to the sheet "Selfservice" to rows with the headers deefined in Selfservice!A2:C2
    ' Define the search-criteria in Selfservice!L1:L2 (currently the word "Selfservice")

    Sheets("LagerlisteHW").Range("B5").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Selfservice").Range("L1:L2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("Selfservice").Range("A2:C2"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

This works just fine.
Negative side effect is the following:

Whenever I change a cell in sheet1, the filters stop working and even vanish from the selected line. 
I have to manually click in the filter-icon and have to select the filters as before. 
This is, oh wonder, more than inconvenient. 
Does anyone know a workaround and/or a fix for this "feature"?

In addition I can't copy and paste multiple times - just once. Then the cell is no longer selected with the moving-dotted-line.

Is this due to the .xlsm-format or did I mess something up?

Kind regards